# Would this be an acceptable solution for a Polyfill for JavaScript bind method?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

First I copy the current passed context into dummy.
Then I add a method fn as the currently passed Function.
The dummy object exists in the closure.
Finally I'll return a function which executes the `dummy.fn` with the initially passed arguments.

```
Function.prototype.bind2 = function(context, ...args){
    var dummy = {...context}
    dummy.fn = this
    return function(){
        return dummy.fn(...args)
    }
}
```

Edit 1: After first suggestion for the new dummy object, I changed it to the following

```
Function.prototype.bind2 = function(context, ...args){
    var dummy = Object.create(context)
    dummy.fn = this
    return function(){
        return dummy.fn(...args)
    }
}
```

Edit 2: for the spread operator fix, I've used eval:

```
Function.prototype.bind2 = function(){
    var args = arguments;
    var dummy = Object.create(args[0]);
    dummy.fn = this;
    return function(){
                return eval('dummy.fn('+Object.values(args).slice(1,).join(',')+')') 
           } 
}
```

Comment: A proper polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, from first glance, there's several problems:

- `bind` will invoke the method on the passed context, not a copy of it — your version makes it impossible for the bound function to affect the context directly
- The method of copying an object that you employ will cut an object from its prototype, and also any magic it might have
- `bind` will also allow the function to accept additional parameters that are not bound
- Any environment that would require `bind` to be polyfilled would not be able to handle the `...` spread syntax.

```js
Function.prototype.bind2 = function(context, ...args){
    var dummy = {...context}
    dummy.fn = this
    return function(){
        return dummy.fn(...args)
    }
}

let obj = Object.create({
  name: "an obj",
  getName: function() { return this.name; },
  setFoo: function() { this.foo = 42; },
  showBarBaz: function(bar, baz) { console.log(bar, baz) }
});
obj.setFoo.bind2(obj)();                 // does not set `obj.foo`
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.getName.bind2(obj)());   // no access to prototype
obj.showBarBaz.bind2(obj, "bar")("baz"); // does not pass "baz"

obj.setFoo.bind(obj)();                  // sets `obj.foo`
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.getName.bind(obj)());    // full access to prototype
obj.showBarBaz.bind(obj, "bar")("baz");  // passes "baz"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip,

I've fixed the first part of the copy object by creating a new object through the prototype of the context.  

    `Function.prototype.bind2 = function(context, ...args){
        var dummy = Object.create(context);
        dummy.fn = this;
        return function(){  
            return dummy.fn(...args)  
        }  
    }  `

Still struggling on the spread syntax on the arguments.